# Bimodality of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

Consider an eigenvalue / eigenvector problem for a matrix $A$:

$$\sum_j A_{ij} x_j = \lambda x_i$$

Under what conditions is $x_i$ unimodal in $i$? That is, up to a multiplicative constant, is $x_{i+1} \ge x_i$ for the first values of $i$, and then $x_{i+1} \le x_i$ for later values? Or is $x_i$ bimodal? How many peaks does it have?

Obviously I don't expect answers to such broad questions. This is "reference-request" question, or a terminology question. I need to know if this type of problem has been considered, perhaps for very specific matrices, and what are the relevant keywords (if there are any) to search in google scholar. Are there results in the literature related to this?

Comment: You clearly need a context that's richer than just linear algebra, since changing the basis by permuting the basis vectors reorders the $x_i$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have a fixed basis.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think that OP stated the question badly when he/she talked about $x_{i+1} \ge x_i$, etc., but the question is perfectly meaningful if you just ask "Can we predict any important statistical properties of the distribution of eigenvector entries for any class of matrices?"

Comment: @sasquires No. As I said, I consider the basis fixed. Then imagine you plot the components of the eigenvector agains the index. Is this plot unimodal? How many peaks / valleys does it have?

Comment: @becko Ok, then I basically agree with Ethan that the question is meaningless.  There's no way for me to predict anything about the particular basis that you happen to be using.  The vast majority of the tools of linear algebra are elegant and powerful precisely because they are basis-independent.  The other question (the statistical distribution of eigenvector entries given a matrix) is actually meaningful and is closely related to your question and may actually give you the information that you want, so you should carefully consider whether you want to reject it.

Comment: @sasquires I don't think Ethan said the question is meaningless, he just said that the typical linear algebra theorems won't be much helpful, which I suspected.

Comment: @becko Ok, I mostly agree.  The question has a reasonably well-defined meaning, albeit one that is far outside the scope of linear algebra.  However, the part that still strikes me as meaningless, or at least poorly worded, is the use of "bimodality" in the title and related words in the question.  These words ordinarily refer to a probability distribution or a statistical realization of such a distribution.  What you are actually asking is whether $x_i$ is monotonic as a function of $i$, or more generally, how many peaks it has, rather than anything related to probability distributions.

Comment: @sasquires Precisely. I did not mention the word probability.

Comment: @becko Your response makes no sense.  My comment was that "bimodality" is a term that is only defined in probability theory, and that you were misusing it.

Comment: @sasquires A bimodal function is a function with two maxima. It doesn't have to be a probability distribution.

Comment: @becko I've never heard the term "bimodal function" outside of the concept of probability/statistics before.  I would venture to say that the majority of mathematicians haven't either.  You can define the term however you want, but it is misleading.  Anyway, I've made my point and you've made yours, so I am going to stop after this comment.

Comment: @sasquires Do you know of a more appropriate word to describe "bimodality" in the sense I am using it? If so I can edit my question

Comment: I would just say that $x_i$, as a function of $i$, has more than one peak (or local maximum).

Comment: @sasquires On the other hand, I would be specially interested in the case that $A$ is non-negative and irreducible (so Perron-Frobenius applies). In this case, you can assume that $x_i$ is positive, and normalized, *i.e.*, a probability distribution.

Comment: If $A$ is a non-negative matrix, then you should read the references below (and follow reference trails within).  But I should note that you can come up with a probability distribution for the $x_i$ regardless of whether they are positive or normalized.  (The probability $p(x)$ is what has to be positive and normalized, not the $x_i$ themselves.)  But this assumes that you are treating $A$ as a random member of some class of matrices.  Most of the references I gave (e.g. the Wigner distribution) are for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, as you do, that this question only has a nice or simple answer for very particular cases.  Here are the cases that I can think of.

Wigner studied a class of random matrices and showed that the eigenvalues follow a particulr distribution.  It looks like the corresponding eigenvalue distribution has also been studied in [1] below, though I haven't read the paper.  This is a very restricted case and hence I expect it to have very rigorous results.

There is only one case where I have personally read any papers that address this issue, and even then it is addressed only obliquely.  The case in question is the Frobenius-Perron eigenvector of non-negative matrices.  The results are only fully trustworthy to a physicist when the matrix satisfies some minimal amount of randomness or well-connectedness, and to a mathematician they would lack sufficient rigor.

It has been a long time since I've read any of these papers, but the basic idea is that you can consider $A^n \sim \lambda^n x v^T$ (where $\lambda$, $x$, and $v$ are the Frobenius-Perron eigenvalue and right and left Frobenius-Perron eigenvectors, respectively), then relate various properties of $A$ to $\lambda$, $x$, and $v$.

The results are mainly of interest to the complex networks community, because complex networks can be represented by an adjacency matrix whose spectrum predicts important properties of dynamics occurring on the network.  [2] and [3] below are a couple of relevant papers of this type, and the references may give more.

There is an associated field of finding community structure in networks by looking at the spectrum of a matrix.  My recollection is that this is more general but may be slightly less rigorous than the last paragraph.  It is more general in the sense that the results will apply There are quite a few papers on this subject, since community structure was a hot topic for most of the last 15 years.  [4] is an example of such a paper, and the same author has written quite a lot more on the subject.

None of this comes anywhere close to answering your general question, but this post is too long for a comment!

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0057

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4503

[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1465

[4] https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0605087